# Struts2 addFieldError not working in project with annotations

Tags: jsp, validation, struts2, annotations

I have a webapplication project developed with struts2 and I want to remove some code from `struts.xml` using annotations.

I edited my web.xml in order to tell struts to get all the actions from the package com.anthonybanche.actions and I added in all my actions the annotations needed to handle the results.

an example of what I needed to add:

```
@InterceptorRefs({
    @InterceptorRef("defaultStack"),
})
@Results({
       @Result(type="chain", name="ok", location="preload"),,
       @Result(name="invalid.token", location="/errore/tokenerror.jsp"),
       @Result(name="errore", location="/errore/internalerror.jsp"),
    })
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
```

In my insert action I have a validate method that call other specified validate functions like this one:

```
public boolean validateVuoti(){
    //Controlla che i campi del form non siano vuoti
    boolean result=true;
    if(tipo.equals("")){
        addFieldError("tipo","Campo necessario!");
        result=false;
    }
    if(dimensioni.equals("")){
        addFieldError("dimensioni","Campo necessario!");
        result=false;
    }
```

When validation fails this line calls an action called preload that retrieves some data from DB and shows again the insert.jsp page with the combobox filled in with the data that the previsious action has got.

```
@Result(type="chain", name="input", location="preload"),,
```

When the actions were mapped using the "classic" struts.xml file this system worked correctly and when the validation control failed the program used to show me the errors. now the validation control fails and the preload action is performed but no error message is shown.

Someone has any idea about how to fix this?

Comment: Is this (annotations vs xml) the only change you made to the project ? Or have you upgraded Struts, changed theme, configuration etc. ? P.S: Chain usage is officially discouraged

Comment: You shouldn't use `chain` for preserving error messages, but take a look at chain interceptors parameters: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/chaining-interceptor.html.

Comment: What are those annotations? Did you use them along with `struts.xml`?

Comment: i also updated struts to 2.3.16.3 and added all the libraries needed for using annotations in struts. What should I use instead of chaining?

Comment: If you need to do redirect and preserve messages then take a look at message store interceptor.